# How to script a button click based on Label or Identifier

Tags: applescript

I'm writing a script in AppleScript that ends with a button press in an application. The issue, however, is that the button has no Attribute Title. I've run Accessibility Inspector and UI Browser over it and the AXTitle is <empty string>.

I can call the button by its number, but everyone on my team has this application set up slightly differently based on their own workflow and the stupid button has a different identifying number depending on where the window is. The window can be a detached pop-up, or attached to the main application window on either the left or the right. All three options yield a different index address.

Button Index when attached to the left:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Application Name"
    click button 8 of splitter group 1 of front window of application 
    process "Application Name" of application "System Events"
end tell
```

Button Index when attached to the right:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Application Name"
    click button 9 of splitter group 1 of front window of application 
    process "Application Name" of application "System Events"
end tell
```

Button Index when window is detached and floating:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Application Name"
    click button 8 of front window of application process "Application    
    Name" of application "System Events"
end tell
```

The constant between the locations is the button label and the button identifier, but I'm having trouble getting script editor to recognize the button based on the Identifier or Prepared Response. I don't know if it's just not possible or if I'm simply writing the code wrong.

When I try to use either the Label or Identifier I get the errors

```
click button "Prepared Response" of front window
```

**Script Error** System Events got an error: Can’t get button "Prepared Response" of window 1 of process "Application Name".

```
click button "_NS:667" of front window
```

**Script Error** System Events got an error: Can’t get button "_NS:667" of window 1 of process "Application Name".

```
click button with "Prepared Response" of front window
```

**Syntax Error** Expected “into”, variable name, class name, other parameter name or property but found “"”.

```
click button with label "Prepared Response" of front window
```

**Syntax Error** Expected “given”, “with”, “without”, other parameter name, etc. but found “"”.

The only two restrictions are that the code has to be AppleScript - not Javascript - and that I can't require my team members to install an application

Comment: What application is it?  What about other attributes or properties besides `AXTitle`?

Comment: It's an in-house proprietary application that my NDA prevents me from naming in a public forum. It has label, enabled, frame, help, identifier, position, role and size. No title and no value.

Comment: Those are properties, and they sound like properties of a window, not a button.  Don’t forget there are also attributes, which are distinct from properties.  Run the line `tell app "System Events" to tell process AppName to return the {name, value} of every attribute of button 8 of splitter group 1 of window 1` (or whatever reference works for you on your system), and that’ll give you a list of names and values for attributes you can use to identity the button.  You can do the same with `every property` (`description` and `role description` sometimes have useful values).

Comment: {{"AXRole", "AXHelp", "AXEnabled", "AXWindow", "AXSize", "AXTitle", "AXRoleDescription", "AXTopLevelUIElement", "AXFocused", "AXDescription", "AXParent", "AXPosition", "AXFrame", "AXIdentifier"}, {"AXButton", "Responses", true, window "Email" of application process "AppName" of application "System Events", {31, 19}, "", "button", missing value, false, "Response", window "Email" of application process "AppName" of application "System Events", {1693, 105}, {1693, 105, 1724, 124}, "_NS:667"}}

Comment: `AXHelp`, `AXDescription` and `AXIdentifier` each look like viable candidates for uniquely identifying that button.  I saw you tried to use `"_NS:667"`, but you did so incorrectly, as you tried to substitute it in for the name of the button, but you cannot do that.  You can do: `tell app "System Events" to tell process AppName to tell window 1 to get the first button whose value of attribute "AXIdentifier" = "_NS:667"`, or similarly with those other two attributes, depending which you think is best to use. Then this should work across all systems, regardless.

Comment: Likewise, if you wish to use a property (rather than an attribute), and if `label` or `identifier` are the names of two of those properties with values that are useful to you, you can do: `...the first button whose label = ...` or `...whose identifier = ...`.  I suspect it has a property called `description` (which corresponds to the attribute `AXDescription`), so you might be able to do `...whose description = "Response"`.  But `AXIdentifier` is probably a good bet, assuming it’s the same on all systems, which I think it should be.

Comment: @CJK well dang. **Script Error** System Events got an error: Can’t get attribute "AXIdentifier". Same error with AXDescription. AXHelp gave the error **Script Error** System Events got an error: Can’t get button 1 of window 1 of process "AppName" whose value of attribute "AXHelp" = "Responses". Invalid index.

Comment: Label and Identifier on their own gave an error that the variable wasn't defined. Description gave the same error as AXHelp. **Script Error** System Events got an error: Can’t get button 1 of window 1 of process "AppName" whose description = "Responses". Invalid index.

Comment: Odd.  If you’re sure you’re not omitting a splitter group or something from your reference, and that the code is correct, I’m puzzled why that doesn’t work when you clearly **are** able to access those attributes (as you provided the list of their names and values above).  I suspect you may have a typo in your code or some small omission somewhere, but without seeing it myself and playing with the application first-hand, I’m limited in what I can do from here.  It was worth trying, though.

Comment: Reading all of the comments to your post, I decided to add a .gif at the bottom of my answer which demonstrates using Automator.app's "Watch Me Do" to record me clicking on some buttons in System Preferences, then copying those actions to Script Editor and using elements of that code to identify buttons and windows etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach that may work for you.

AppleScript has the ability to change `property` values and save those new `property` values on every run of the script.  However, if the script gets recompiled at any time, those new `property` values that have been changed will be lost and set back to their original values.

In this following code I set the variable `property launchCount : 0` and a few lines down I set another variable `set launchCount to launchCount + 1` .  So every time the script runs, the `property launchCount : 0` will change from 0 to 1 then 2 then 3 etc...

The purpose of this approach is is that with each individual computer that runs the script for the first time, A `choose from list` dialog appears, asking the user to select their window location.  That choice will then be stored in another variable `property windowIsLocated`. Next was to set up a handler with a conditional clause... ex: `if windowIsLocated is this then do that else if windowIsLocated is that then do this`

```
property launchCount : 0
property windowIsLocated : missing value

set launchCount to launchCount + 1

set theList to {"Window Attached To Left", "Window Attached To Right", "Window Is Floating"}

if launchCount is 1 then
    set windowLocation to choose from list theList ¬
        with title "Window Location" with prompt ¬
        "Please Choose The Location Of Your Window" OK button name ¬
        "OK" cancel button name ¬
        "Cancel" multiple selections allowed false ¬
        without empty selection allowed
    set windowIsLocated to item 1 of windowLocation
end if

clickTheButton() -- use this anywhere in your script to click the button 

to clickTheButton()
    if windowIsLocated is "Window Attached To Left" then
        tell application "Application Name"
            activate
            repeat until frontmost
                delay 0.1
            end repeat
        end tell
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "Application Name"
            click button 8 of splitter group 1 of front window
        end tell
    else if windowIsLocated is "Window Attached To Right" then
        tell application "Application Name"
            activate
            repeat until frontmost
                delay 0.1
            end repeat
        end tell
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "Application Name"
            click button 9 of splitter group 1 of front window
        end tell
    else if windowIsLocated is "Window Is Floating" then
        tell application "Application Name"
            activate
            repeat until frontmost
                delay 0.1
            end repeat
        end tell
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "Application Name"
            click button 8 of front window
        end tell
    end if
end clickTheButton
```

---

Reading all of the comments to your post, I decided to add a .gif which demonstrates using Automator.app's "Watch Me Do" to record me clicking on some buttons in System Preferences, then copying those actions to Script Editor and using elements of that code to identify buttons and windows etc.

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic and solved my issue. I was able to use your code twice in the same script - once for the part I described and once for the part I didn't realize would happen once I got past the first hurdle. But both instances were able to use the same windowIsLocated variable. Now if only there was some way to close a Popover window, but all my research indicates that AppleScript can't close Popovers.

Comment: @Michel Keep in mind, it's possible the code in my solution could have been shorter. Not knowing the application name or seeing your entire script or any screenshots of the windows of the application, makes it difficult to be able to provide a "spot on" solution.

Comment: I understand. I wish I could just throw the entire script up as that would make things much easier to troubleshoot, but there's too much identifying information. Posting it is what my old manager would call a "career limiting move". ha.

Comment: thanks for the gif.  I learned how to record actions with automator and copy to script editor.  Solved my long standing issue.

Answer (score 1):

I find `get properties` useful for debugging:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Application Name"
  get properties of every UI element of front window
end tell
```

You'll get a bunch of junk, and nearly all of it might be `(missing value)` for the app you're trying to script. But some of them will be filled out, such as `description`. Once you've figured that out, you can cut the all the noise out by doing:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Application Name"
  get description of every UI element of front window
end tell
```

However, UI elements are nested. For example you won't get the toolbar buttons, you might just get `"toolbar"` as the description of the second element. Not very useful...

To get the toolbar buttons you can do:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Application Name"
  get description of every UI element of toolbar 1 of front window
end tell
```

From there, you should easily be able to find the toolbar button you want. Then it's a simple matter of doing:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Application Name"
  repeat with uiElement in UI elements of toolbar 1 of front window
    if description of uiElement is "Do The Thing" then
      click uiElement
    end if
  end repeat
end tell
```